# Finding the flux through a circle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces, vectors, matrix-calculus

For a two-by-two matrix $A$, find the flux of a linear vector field ${\bf F}(x,y)=A\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ through a unit circle with the center at the origin in terms of entries of $A$.

I don't quite understand what to put inside the integration here I'm confused as to how ${\bf F}$ acts on the unit circle. And should I use $x= r \cos t$ and $y = r \sin t$ for the circle or a function of radius $r$?

Comment: Do you mind to check if I have understood correctly your notations?

Comment: Yes, it is correct @RobertZ

Comment: Yes thank you. Do you mind answering how to choose which x, y, and n to use in a problem like this?

Comment: ${\bf n}$ is the outer normal to the curve $\gamma$. $({\bf F} \cdot {\bf n})$ is the scalar product of the given vector field and ${\bf n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that  the flux of ${\bf F}(x,y)=(F_x(x,y),F_y(x,y))$ through a given closed curve $\gamma$ is
$$\int_{\gamma} ({\bf F} \cdot {\bf n}) ds$$
where ${\bf n}$ is the outward unit normal vector field to $\gamma$.

If $\gamma$ is the circle of radius $r$ centred at the origin then the outer normal is given by ${\bf n}=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$, hence
$$\int_{\gamma} ({\bf F} \cdot {\bf n}) ds=\int_0^{2\pi}[F_x(r\cos(t),r\sin(t))\cos(t)+F_y(r\cos(t),r\sin(t))\sin(t)] (rdt).$$

In your case, $r=1$,  $F_x(x,y)=a_{11}x+a_{12}y$ and $F_y(x,y)=a_{21}x+a_{22}y$.
Now you can compute the above integral and find a formula in terms of the elements of the matrix $A$.

By the [Divergence Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivergenceTheorem.html) you will find that the flux is

$$\int_D \nabla \cdot {\bf F} \, dA = 
\int_D (a_{11}+a_{22}) \, dA=(a_{11}+a_{22})|D|=\pi(a_{11}+a_{22})$$
where $D$ is the interior of $\gamma$.